# What does "what the morrow may not bring forth" mean?

Tags: meaning, the-markenmore-mystery, j-s-fletcher

In *[The Markenmore Mystery](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/59818/59818-h/59818-h.htm#toc1)* (1922) by J. S. Fletcher, a man was talking to a detective in a bar:

> “Don’t forget, Mr. Blick—though a gentleman of your ability and experience needs no reminding of it, I’m sure—don’t forget that it’s always the unexpected that happens! The unexpected, sir!—**Ah, there’s a great deal in the unexpected!** No one knows, sir, **what the morrow may not bring forth**!”

I usually find this statement in a positive form, i.e "No one know what the morrow may bring forth", but what it's meant by making it in a negative form this time?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's double negation — something that is not allowed in formal English, but is very common in informal English. (For example, in the *Rolling Stones* song "I Can't Get No Satisfaction".)

What does it mean? It means exactly the same thing as the positive form would:

> No one knows what the morrow may bring forth!

Why did the author use the negative form here? I don't know. Possibly to give a more accurate representation of dialog, or possibly to give some indication as to the level of education of the speaker. It would take more context to figure this out.

Comment: The specific implication I read is "No one knows what won't happen tomorrow, thus anything could happen"

Comment: @bobble:you're right, in this case the slang double negation means the same as the standard English interpretation. So we can figure out what it means, but don't know what the exact grammar is.